# How to differentiate whether a call to SAP is from OData API or Fiori app

Tags: odata, sapui5, abap, sap-fiori

I have a requirement to find whether the call to the specific application is from Odata API call ( Third-party ) or Fiori app

Third-party applications will use our OData API to call those transactions.

I'm using the FM **GUI_GET_DESKTOP_INFO** to identify whether it's from GUI or Fiori app.

Now I have conflict in finding whether it's from **Third-party** app or **Fiori** app

Comment: Keep in mind that anybody can simply open a tool like Postman and start issuing OData requests to your APIs. Whatever header or body field you are looking at might not be hard to forge. Also keep in mind that universal API forms like OData have exactly the purpose to make the server agnostic of the type of consumer.

Comment: I am not aware of SAP GUI or SAP WebDynpro using OData APIs. As far as I know they use the poprietary protocol SAP DATA. But I may be mistaken on this, not an expert in these older technologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your Fiori app consumes the same OData service as your oData API , and at Gateway you cannot tell the consumer.

Of course for your Fiori app , you can put some indicator in the HTTP call(Header) or similar approach to let Gateway knows that those requests are sent from your Fiori App. but cusumer of OData API can do the same to trick your backend logic.

If you have strong business reason to differentiate the consumer, please consider to have a separate oData API( new OData service and reuse your backend logic as much as possible).