# How to know current browser's URL in SAP ABAP class

Tags: abap, sap-fiori

Currently, I need to find whether the user's action is from the Fiori launchpad or any other APIs(postman).

After the user's action, it will trigger my ABAP class. So, there I need to capture the current URL.

So, if I know the browser's current URL, then I can distinguish between the Fiori app or other third-party APIs.

Your inputs are appreciated

Comment: In normal web apps you could use the HTTP `User-Agent` header. It doesn't contain the URL but its purpose is just what you're looking for. If your API/code returns only data I would opt against a different behaviour for different HTTP clients/user agents. It feels wrong for me.

Comment: BTW: This question basically looks like a duplicate of YOUR OWN other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60651304/how-to-differentiate-whether-a-call-to-sap-is-from-odata-api-or-fiori-app where @Florian already pointed out: "Also keep in mind that universal API forms like OData have exactly the purpose to make the server agnostic of the type of consumer."

Answer (score -2):

Actually we don't require to use any **FMs** or **Utility classes** to know the current URL.

We need to check the Debugger call stack. You need to drill down the stack and check the available local variables and objects.

In my scenario, I have drilled down the stack and found an object which is having the base URL which I'm looking for. I have imported that URL into my calling method and written my functionality to check whether it's a third-party API or Fiori app.

Comment: Glad you found a solution and thank you for describing it (Maybe you can add the exact class or FM you found the URL in?) Still, for anyone else reading this: Although making the behaviour of code dependent on the call stack is somewhat common for certain problems in ABAP I'd consider it bad style. Modular code should behave different depending on the parameters you provide, not on from where it's called.

Comment: This is not a good answer. First, you should name the actual class/object you came across. Second, this wires your ABAP class to the http callstack: your class will never work outside of an http request, which may be a bad shame for a lot of functionality that you might want to trigger from background processing etc in the future. The better solution is to extract the URL in some controller-like outer object, then pass it down your own call stack in a kind of context object.